# jax.numpy.delete assume_unique_indices unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, jax

I can not seem to get the assume_unique_indices from jax.numpy working. According to the documentation [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.delete.html), the jnp.delete has a keyword argument "assume_unique_indices" that is supposed to make this function jit compatible when we are sure that the index array is an integer array and is guaranteed to contain unique entries.

Here is an minimum reproducible example

```
import jax

arr = jnp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
idx = jnp.array([0, 2, 4])

print(jax.__version__)

# Delete elements at indices idx
out = jax.numpy.delete(arr, idx, assume_unique_indices=True)

print(out) # [2 4]
```

The error message

```
0.4.8
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bf0277118922> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 
      8 # Delete elements at indices idx
----> 9 out = jax.numpy.delete(arr, idx, assume_unique_indices=False)
     10 
     11 print(out) # [2 4]

TypeError: delete() got an unexpected keyword argument 'assume_unique_indices'
```

Deleting the `assume_unique_indices` made it work as expected.

Comment: Here is an workaround : https://github.com/google/jax/issues/12592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assume_unique_indices` was added in https://github.com/google/jax/pull/15671, after JAX version 0.4.8 was released. If you update to version 0.4.9 or newer, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it turns out, the 'assume_unique_indices' is only added rather recently, updating to jax version 0.4.10 did the trick